# How to open txt file when it appears?

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
with open('id.txt') as file:
   urls = iter([line.strip() for line in file])
```

During the program's running, I need this code to run only when a file `"id.txt"` appears in the program folder. How can I set a rule so that this code will only run when this file appears?

Comment: make the code check if the file exist in the folder and set a task in TaskScheduler to execute the code every X minutes

Comment: as an aside, what is the point of using `iter` here?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I have another function that, when called, iterates and opens tabs in silenium from links in this file

Comment: @kgjfdhvd that isn't a reason to use `iter` here.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ok, anyway, i have another problem

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach is to poll the directory. That mean's list the contents of the directory and if you don't see the file, sleep for a little while, then look again.

The more sophisticated solution (on linux) is to use the inotify facility of the kernel and subscribe to changes in the directory. This is a third party wrapper for that: https://pypi.org/project/inotify/

Similar solutions may exist on windows and mac.